# Which tag needs to have 5 score?

Tags: support, feature-request

I tried to suggest a synonym, but I still need 5 score on a tag.

[image]

*Which* tag needs to have more score? [units](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/units) or [blender-units](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blender-units)?

Perhaps the phrasing of this error could be clarified to specify which tag doesn't meet the requirements?

Answer (score 2):

I checked my profile, and as I have `9` score on [blender-units](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blender-units), it appears to be the tag which you are proposing as the master/parent tag (in this case, [units](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/units)).

I still feel like I shouldn't have to check my profile though.. What if I didn't have > 5 score in either? There would be no way to tell which I need to improve.

Comment: I went ahead and made the changes.